# Item update query produced by django is wrong

Tags: python, django, timescaledb

I am trying to update one item at a time using the Django ORM with [TimescaleDB](https://www.timescale.com/) as my database.

I have a timesacle hypertable defined by the following model:

```
class RecordTimeSeries(models.Model):

    # NOTE: We have removed the primary key (unique constraint) manually, since we don't want an id column
    timestamp = models.DateTimeField(primary_key=True)
    location = PointField(srid=settings.SRID, null=True)
    station = models.ForeignKey(Station, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    # This is a ForeignKey and not an OneToOneField because of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61205063/error-cannot-create-a-unique-index-without-the-column-date-time-used-in-part)
    record = models.ForeignKey(Record, null=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    temperature_celsius = models.FloatField(null=True)

    class Meta:
        unique_together = (
            "timestamp",
            "station",
            "record",
        )
```

When I update the item using `save()`:

```
record_time_series = models.RecordTimeSeries.objects.get(
    record=record,
    timestamp=record.timestamp,
    station=record.station,
)

record_time_series.location=record.location
record_time_series.temperature_celsius=temperature_celsius
record_time_series.save()
```

I get the following error:

```
psycopg2.errors.UniqueViolation: duplicate key value violates unique constraint "5_69_db_recordtimeseries_timestamp_station_id_rec_0c66b9ab_uniq"
DETAIL:  Key ("timestamp", station_id, record_id)=(2022-05-25 09:15:00+00, 2, 2) already exists.
```

and I see that the query that django used is the following:

```
{'sql': 'UPDATE "db_recordtimeseries" SET "location" = NULL, "station_id" = 2, "record_id" = 2, "temperature_celsius" = 26.0 WHERE "db_recordtimeseries"."timestamp" = \'2022-05-25T09:15:00\'::timestamp', 'time': '0.007'}
```

On the other hand the update is successful with `update()`:

```
record_time_series = models.RecordTimeSeries.objects.filter(
    record=record,
    timestamp=record.timestamp,
    station=record.station,
)
record_time_series.update(
    location=record.location,
    temperature_celsius=temperature_celsius,
)
```

and the sql used by django is:

```
{'sql': 'UPDATE "db_recordtimeseries" SET "location" = NULL, "temperature_celsius" = 25.0 WHERE ("db_recordtimeseries"."record_id" = 2 AND "db_recordtimeseries"."station_id" = 2 AND "db_recordtimeseries"."timestamp" = \'2022-05-25T09:15:00\'::timestamp)', 'time': '0.012'}
```

Obviously, the first query is wrong because it does not have the correct parameters in the `WHERE` clause, but why doesn't django include those parameters, since timestamp is not a unique key, and how can this be fixed?

Answer (score 0):

I think the error was caused because of `foregn_key`:

Firstly:

> Be aware that the update() method is converted directly to an SQL
> statement. It is a bulk operation for direct updates. It doesn’t run
> any save() methods on your models, or emit the pre_save or post_save
> signals (which are a consequence of calling save()), or honor the
> auto_now field option.

[source](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/topics/db/queries/)

Secondly:

> Analogous to ON DELETE there is also ON UPDATE which is invoked when a
> referenced column is changed (updated). The possible actions are the
> same. In this case, CASCADE means that the updated values of the
> referenced column(s) should be copied into the referencing row(s).

[source](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/ddl-constraints.html#DDL-CONSTRAINTS-UNIQUE-CONSTRAINTS)

Comment: in the [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/topics/db/queries/#updating-multiple-objects-at-once) it is metnioned that `You can only set non-relation fields and ForeignKey fields using this method. ... To update ForeignKey fields, set the new value to be the new model instance you want to point to.` So,  `ForeignKey` should not be a problem